# Php variable rewrite to Twig

Tags: php, variables, twig

My rewrite to Twig does not work. What is wrong?

PHP source:

```
<?php foreach ($datas as $data) { ?>
          <?php if ($data['information_id'] == $info_id)  { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $data['href']; ?>" class="list-group active"><?php echo $data['title']; ?></a>              
             <?php } else { ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $data['href']; ?>" class="list-group"><?php echo $data['title']; ?></a> 
             <?php } ?> 
             <?php } ?>
```

Rewrite to Twig:

```
    {% for datas in data %}
            {% if {{ attribute(data,information_id) }} == info_id %}
             <a href="{{ data.href }}" class="list-group active">{{ data.title }}</a>
             {% else %}
             <a href="{{ data.href }}" class="list-group">{{ data.title }}</a>  
             {% endif %}           
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. For example what have you tried so far? Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `{{ data.information_id }}` / `{{ data['information_id'] }}` / `{{  attribute(data, information_id) }}`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{% for data in datas %}
        {% if attribute(data,information_id) == info_id %}
             <a href="{{ data.href }}" class="list-group active">{{ data.title }}</a>
        {% else %}
             <a href="{{ data.href }}" class="list-group">{{ data.title }}</a>  
        {% endif %}           
{% endfor %}
```

You only need to wrap variables in `{{ }}` when you're outputting them to the page.  Not in the middle of an `{% if %}` statement.

Also I've swapped round `{% for datas in data %}` to `{% for data in datas %}`.  I'm assuming `datas` is the array, and `data` is each individual item.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html